# concatenate stdin and output of command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read from stdin, then concatenate stdin and a transformed version of it. For example concatenate stdin and the reverse of it, which is transformed by the `rev` command.

Input: *hello*

Output *hello\nolleh*

How this can be done via a one-liner pipeline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example like this:

```
echo hello | tee >(rev)
```

`>( )` is bash process substitution. So tee writes into a subshell's stdin in which `rev` is executed. rev then writes the reverse to stdout. And tee also writes to stdout the unchanged stdin.

Comment: Thanks, works greatly. Can you give me some explanation? I've never used `tee` before.

Comment: @WonderCsabo: `tee` copies stdin to stdout (i.e., passes input through as output) while simultaneously allowing capturing the same input in a file (or even multiple ones) - see `man tee`. In the case at hand, `>(...)` acts as a pseudo (output) file; the enclosed command receives the data via stdin.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a /proc filesystem, you can do:

```
{ echo hello | tee /proc/self/fd/3 | rev; } 3>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `read` loop to read from stdin.

```
echo hello | while read s; do echo -e "$s\n$(rev <<< "$s")"; done
```

Or without the loop:

```
read s < <(echo hello); echo -e "$s\n$(rev <<< "$s")"
```